# Как добавить кнопку рядом с кнопкой пуск?

Tags: c#, windows-10

Как добавить кнопку рядом с кнопкой пуск?

Сюда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какую кнопку нужно?

Comment: кнопку запуска своей программы

Comment: ярлык создавали?

Comment: ну можно создать

Comment: ну создайте на рабочем столе, и методом перетаскивания переместите куда нужно

Comment: ярлык добавляется на панель а не рядом с пуском

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59354/discussion-between-aliaksandr-pitkevich-and-codename0082016).